# Consola h2 no muestra una de mis tablas

Tags: java, spring, h2

Tengo mi proyecto Spring Boot, corro el proyecto, y la consola h2 sólo me muestra la tabla Post, y no la de User

[image: imagen de consola de h2]

La clase post está hecha de la siguiente manera

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_post", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 255)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

Pero la clase User la tengo de la siguiente manera

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String email;

    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private final List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", birthDate=" + birthDate +
                ", posts=" + posts +
                '}';
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String email, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String email, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

   //getters and setters
}
```

Tengo una función donde creo varios usuarios pero al momento de ejecutarlo se rompe la aplicación, no creo ningún post, pero al momento de correr la aplicación sólo me muestra la consola la tabla de Post y la terminal me muestra

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists post CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table post (id_post bigint generated by default as identity, description varchar(255), user_id_user bigint, primary key (id_post))
Hibernate: create table user (id_user bigint not null, birth_date date, email varchar(50), name varchar(50), primary key (id_user))
Hibernate: alter table post add constraint FKk2pskk356iip08omsx3t2x0qm foreign key (user_id_user) references user
```

Comment: Lo solucioné agregando la siguiente linea en el properties `
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` para que se solucionara

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo problema y lo solucioné de igual manera añadiendo esta línea de código al archivo application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

una recomendación adicional.
Existen problemas asociados al nombre de tabla con nombre literal "user", Spring me arrojaba esto al momento de ejecutar el proyecto : Syntax error in SQL statement "drop table if exists [*]user cascade "; expected "identifier";].
Dicho problema lo solucioné de tan solo cambiar el nombre de la tabla user por cualquier otro nombre.